How to pass an empty value to a SQL Server database?
Right now it's working fine, but this does not feel like it's the right way to do it. The Profilefoto is the only value that is nullable, also in the database. This is the script right now, I check if the value is null and I do the same script twice, the only difference is the image:
public int InsertInDb()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        if (Profilefoto != null)
        {
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Person (firstname, lastname, login, password, profilephoto, regdate, isadmin) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES (@par1, @par2, @par3, @par4, @par5, @par6, @par7)", conn);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par1", Firstname);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par2", Lastname);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par3", Login);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par4", Wachtwoord);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par5", Utils.ImageToString(Profilefoto));
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par6", RegDate);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par7", IsAdmin);

            Id = (int)comm.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        else
        {
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Person (firstname, lastname, login, password, regdate, isadmin) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES (@par1, @par2, @par3, @par4, @par5, @par6)", conn);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par1", Firstname);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par2", Lastname);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par3", Login);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par4", Wachtwoord);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par5", RegDate);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par6", IsAdmin);

            Id = (int)comm.ExecuteScalar();
        }

        return Id;
    }
}

How can I make this more efficient?

Please do yourself a favor and look into Dapper or Entity Framework. This is prehistoric code, rubbing sticks together to make fire. On your question: You should be able to pass DbNull.Value as value. So comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par5", Profilefoto is null ? DbNull.Value : Utils.ImageToString(Profilefoto)); or something along those lines.

oooh okay, I tried just passing null, that did not work so

Agree with @RobIII on DbNull.Value. Disagree (strongly) on the rest. It's a case of horses for courses; use what makes sense in the environment and for the future you anticipate. EF & its competition (just a layer or two up, built on the lower level layer you are using) are powerful (+), hide complexity (+ && -), come with a performance and learning curve cost (-) etc. Nothing is best, just better for circumstances.

@AlanK "Disagree (strongly) on the rest" Agree to disagree. Yes, EF has it's learning curve, Dapper has a much lower, even barely any, learning curve if you're coming from plain ADO.Net code. You're not doing yourself any favors staying stuck in the dark ages. because of a minor learning curve. You can be up-an-running with Dapper in under 15 minutes.
